# How to use ternary operator in Vue template with filter?

Tags: javascript, function, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have an app to set a filter depending on desktop or mobile design, but the ternary operator doesn't work.

Here is the component call:

```
<Metric
    prefix="R$"
    :is-numeric-subvalue="false"
    :is-total="true"
    subvalue="Abril à Maio"
    title="Disponível"
    :value="highlightData.available | defineFilter()"
/>
```

Here is my method to define the filter:

```
methods: {
  defineFilter () {
    const test = true
    const filter = test ? this.$options.filters.decimal(0) : this.$options.filters.shortedNumber()
    return filter
  }
}
```

My filters:

```
filters: {
  decimal: decimalFilter,
  shortedNumber: shortedNumberFilter
}
```

I received the warning:

> [Vue warn]: Failed to resolve filter: defineFilter

Comment: it looks good to me . why do you think its not working?

Comment: @NileshPatel i don't know, isn't working Vue returns the warn "Failed to resolve filter: defineFilter"

Comment: That's because it's in your `methods`.  Move it to `filters`.

Comment: @Dan but how? move my method defineFilter to filters?

Comment: Yes, filters are just functions too

Comment: @Dan I tried to, but i received Cannot read property "$options" of undefined

Comment: As a general rule, you shouldn't use `$options` in your component.  What sort of data are you filtering?  It looks more like you want a method there anyway

Comment: @Dan I'm filtering any number, the question is that the filter causes it to be formatted with a different display and this formatted data must be passed as a prop for the child component

Comment: Which variable contains the number?

Comment: @Dan is a vuex mapState, called "highlightData.available" in this case is equal to 1805.85

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your filter to `filters` and remove both methods.  The filter will receive the number value as an argument.  Since there is no `this` access to the component in a filter, you can use your predefined functions directly:

```js
filters: {
  defineFilter(num) {
    const test = true;
    return test ? decimalFilter(num) : shortedNumberFilter(num);
  }
}
```

Make sure that both of your external functions are prepared to receive the number and return a value.  Here's a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/z5vr0utp/)